# Java Finalizers, what tasks are really necessary

Tags: java, arrays, object, dynamic-arrays

```
ArrayList<Object> foo;
Object[] bar;
```

typical finalizers will do

```
foo = null;
bar = null;
```

My question, will ArrayList call a finalizer wich sets any pointers it holds to null, or do I have to step through the list an do

```
for(i=1; i<foo.size(); i++) foo.set(i,null); ???
```

And the other question: for an array, do I need to set any of its contents to null, like

```
for(i=1; i<bar.length; i++) bar[i] = null;
```

or is it enough that the whole memory block is discarded and any pointer in it out of scope afterwards?

Sorry, if the question is stupid.

After reading through the answers I figured out, that there is nothing to implement there on your own.

Some sources suggest that if something like this (memory eating apps) happens, that this is by bad design.

My core question is: Doing often

```
struct = new LargeStructure();
```

does this exaust memory?

Or does this only need the memory of one of this structures?

BTW: The problem occours in a webapp running tomcat, and there is only one session active wich holds the described pointer as a session variable.

Answer (score 4):

All objects will be eligible for GC by Garbage collector automatically when they are no longer referenced. You don't have to worry about it. If you are setting the array reference to `null` , then the array object itself is eligible for GC if there are no other live reference to the array object, the elements of the array will be eligible for GC if there are no live references to them anymore.

As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29):

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable
```

> Called by the garbage collector on an object **when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object.** A subclass overrides the finalize method to dispose of system resources or to perform other cleanup.

The `finalize()` method will be called after the GC detects that the object is no longer reachable, and before it actually reclaims the memory used by the object. If the object never becomes unreachable, or the GC doesn't run then `finalize()` may never be called.

You can **try** to force the JVM to call `finalize()` by calling [System.runFinalization()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#runFinalization%28%29):

> Runs the finalization methods of any objects pending finalization.
>
> Calling this method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine **expend effort** toward running the finalize methods of objects that have been found to be discarded but whose finalize methods have not yet been run. **When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to complete all outstanding finalizations.**

Comment: if I set foo = null; willl any sub-structures it references be automatically deleted or will they persist in memory

Comment: I understood finalizers as a routine, wich sets all sub-structures to null to make them elegible for garbage collection

Comment: I really hoped I could solve a problem with large data structures wich are not freed.

Comment: I often do TreePointer = new Tree() making large Sets of data npo longer referenced. But they seem to be not freed and memory is exausted after an hour or so

Comment: can you make it very clear so I can tell my boss who thinks that it is my fault (we all know better c++)

Comment: If you set the `TreePointer` to `null` , the `Tree` object will be eligible for GC if there is no other reference to that `Tree` object anywhere else.

Comment: If I understnd you correctly: A binary tree consisting of tree objects referencing each other will be freed by GC only if there is no more refrerence to the root node

Comment: if the objects aren't reachable from a root node then they will be reclaimed.

Comment: would it be a good Idea to call System.runGC() after discarding very large cascaded structures

Comment: It is same as `System.runFinalization()` , best effort by JVM but not guaranteed results.

Comment: I don't know if that matters, but I overwrite the pointer with a reference to a new Object created by new. Then the old object is no longer referenced. But I don't set it to null.

Comment: Finalizers are almost never necessary in Java.  The GC is almost always smarter than you.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically finalizers let you perform last minute tasks on object before they are reclaimed by garbage collection. In practice however there is no guarantee that they will be called, so they are not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set your object's references to `null` in finalizer block. Finalizer's are tipically used for last chance resource closing, it isn't a good practice, but finalizers can provide you a safety net for resource management.

Answer (score 0):

> My question, will ArrayList call a finalizer wich sets any pointers it holds to null, or do I have to step through the list an do

`ArrayList` will not call a finalizer, a finalizer thread will do that, but you don't have to worry about that. Also, you do not have to go over a list and finalize your elements your self. Java Garbage Collector will figure that one out for you and pick those objects up as long as they are not referenced anywhere else in the code.

> And the other question: for an array, do I need to set any of its contents to null, like

No, same as above. Important thing to remember is that you have no reference to any value in the array, or to the array itself if you want it to be picked up by garbage collector.